# kivy too many indentation

Tags: python, kivy

I wanted to make a small program with an Enemy running towards the left side of the screen and you have to stop him by throwing him away.
I made "Enemy" a subclass of the scatter widget and adding it to my level class.
But it told me that I had ro many indentations.
Here is the code:

```
class Enemy(Scatter):
    intv = NumericProperty(0/10.)
    gravity = NumericProperty(0.01)
    velocity = NumericProperty()
    imgp = StringProperty('enemy.png')
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Enemy, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.My_Clock = Clock#   declaring the clock for later usage
        self.My_Clock.schedule_interval(self.Update, self.intv)
    def Update(self, *args):
        self.x -= 1
        if self.y > 0:
            self.velocity += self.gravity
            self.y -= self.velocity
        else:
            if self.velocity > 0.5:
                print 'death'

class level(Widget):
    zicie = NumericProperty(10)# the variable containg the life of the player
    zloto = NumericProperty(0)
    e_killed = NumericProperty(0)
    intv1 = NumericProperty(2/1.)
    pu = BooleanProperty(True)
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(level, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.l_Clock = Clock
    def Update(self, *args):# this funktion generates enemys
        pass
        #obj = Root.ids.level
        #obj.add_widget(Enemy(pos=(500,0))) # the widget enemy is added here

Root = Builder.load_string('''
FloatLayout:
    level:
        Enemy:
            pos: 500,0


<Enemy>:
    Image:
        pos: root.pos
        source: 'enemy.png'

''')
```

Comment: Please provide the full error including stack trace in the question.

Comment: "It told me I had..." Don't paraphrase errors. Copy and paste them.

Answer (score 2):

```
FloatLayout:
    level:
        Enemy:
```

Widget names must start with an upper case letter if you want to use them in kv language, as kv uses this to distinguish between properties and widgets. In this case, it probably thinks that level is a property in which case the indentation is indeed invalid (though as others have commented you should copy and paste errors to make it easy to confirm things like this).